# How can I fill out a WebApi2 RouteTemplate with parameters to produce a route string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have an HttpRouteCollection containing route template strings, which generally look like "/something/{param1}/{param2}", and I have anonymous objects with values for those parameters, like new { param1 = "a", param2 = "b" }. Is there a preexisting way for me to plug in my values and get the final value of "/something/a/b"? This could maybe be done to some extent with reflection and some replacements, but I'm wondering if there is a standard way to achieve this.
I see a ParsedRoute class inside the reference source that seems to perform this task (https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Routing/ParsedRoute.cs) but it's internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this question is a couple of years old by now, but someone might stumble upon it like I did and I wanted to share how I solved this.

Once you have your `RouteTemplate`, you can use a `TemplateBinder` to bind values to it and build a string. Start by injecting `TemplateBinderFactory` and then do something like this:

```cs
var binder = _templateBinderFactory.Create(template, new RouteValueDictionary());
var result = binder.BindValues(routeValues);
```

I hope that helps someone :-)

Comment: I don't remember what I was trying to do so I can't test but I'll mark this as accepted, thanks.